# What is the Goal of Adaptive AutoSAR

Tags: autosar

What is the main motive of introducing Adaptive Autosar?

> Information provided by Autosar consortium is "AP provides mainly high-performance computing and communication mechanisms and offers flexible software configuration."
> High performance computing will be achieved through many/multi core processors,
> Ethernet will be used for communication
> Application will be programmed in C++ language and POSIX will be used.
> My doubts are :
>
> 1. Multi core is already used in Classic platform
> 2. Since Autosar is completely Software, how usages on many core FPGA etc will be considered in autosar scope.
> 3. Ethernet is also available for Classic Platform.
> 4. How C++ fulfill the motive of flexibility, security and high computation?
> 5. What is contribution of POSIX in Adaptive autosar?

Comment: To me, the mentioning of `POSIX` would imply an operating system that has process IDs, signals, message queues, and IPC primitives.

Answer (score 7):

Classic AUTOSAR (especially AUTOSAR OS) is based on static configuration of OS objects like e.g. tasks (mainly because of and through the largely OSEK-like OS; simply said, AUTOSAR OS is OSEK++).

Main point of adaptive AUTOSAR will be to change that concept, introducing dynamically creatable OS objects. Imagine that an adaptive AUTOSAR system would allow to load executables which were unknown at built time.
(Not discussing here whether that is a safe/secure design.)

Comment: Thanks Yunnosch for your reply.. What does OS objects mean? Is it Task, Alarm, counters etc? How OS objects will be created dynamically? Is it like creating instance for class OS at runtime? Please provide more insight. :)

Comment: @AsthaMishra Yes, OS objects are among other things the examples you mentioned; also OS applications which group the others into protection-relevant groups (as an example of what is NOT already part of OSEK). Creation will be possible dynamically, i.e. os objects will not be restricted to what is desribed in a OIL file.

Answer (score 3):

See my answer :

> 1. Multi core is already used in Classic platform

Yes but it is uC core and the performance.. capability is completely different with uP core i.e some state of the art uP core A53, A57 based.
Why.. uP designed for High Performance Applications.
uC hard to render a HD videos ... but uP does.

> 2. Since Autosar is completely Software, how usages on many core FPGA etc will be considered in autosar scope.

Autosar do not only refer to Software but it turns out Hardware requirements as  following.
Eg. You could not port a POSIX OS compliant to uC
FPGA can be configure as a SoC for that you can even have a uC and uP running on same board. The rest is free to use.. Autosar Classic in uC and Autosar Adaptive in uP.

> 3. Ethernet is also available for Classic Platform.

Autosar Adaptive not even defined what is communication protocol
it just say ara::com following with many Spec and Requirement.. that make vendor or Autosar Provider can implement COM in various way... regards Service Oriented motivations.

> 4. How C++ fulfill the motive of flexibility, security and high computation?

It is hard to explain all in one here...
But to fulfill it, we need a completely new platform supports(called Foundations in Adaptive)
Eg. To handle safety we will not start an application via systemd(Linux) or Init (Android) but we need completely new Function to do it : Execution Manager - Adaptive Autosar.

> 5. What is contribution of POSIX in Adaptive autosar?

It only related to OS requirement, where at least some `"system API"` need to be support by OS. The list of system API you can find in POSIX PSE 51.

Comment: `COM` as in `Component Object Model`?

Comment: No, it stand for Communication stack in Autosar so called ComStack.